# Spring security custom error messages not showing

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I was using a tutorial on this link:

> http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/display-custom-error-message-in-spring-security/

To show a custom error message on login form and I got it at the beginning. But after declaring a **authentication-failure-handler-ref="myAuthErrorHandler"**  for a custom failure authenticator handler I can't see it the custom message on the login form:

[image]

What I am doing wrong? Can anybody explain me what happen and why the '**Invalid username or password**' doesn't show?

Here's the code:

**AuthentificationListener**

```
public class AuthentificationListener implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException ae)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken user = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) ae
            .getAuthentication();


    /* User */


    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()
            + "/abc/main/loginfailed");

}
```

}

**applicationContext.xml:**

```
    <bean id="myAuthErrorHandler" class="org.abc.handler.AuthentificationListener"/>
```

**Spring Security:**

```
    <http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/abc/main/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/abc/main/record/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

    <form-login 

    login-page="/abc/main/login" 

    authentication-failure-handler-ref="myAuthErrorHandler" 

    default-target-url="/abc/main/welcome"

    />


    <logout logout-success-url="/abc/main/logout" />

</http>
```

**login.jsp:**

```
        <c:if test="${not empty error}">
        <div class="errorblock">
            Your login attempt was not successful, try again.<br /> Caused :
            ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
        </div>

    </c:if>
```

**LoginController.java:**

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginerror(ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("error", "true");
    return "login";

}
```

**Update:** To answer on Mani answer, I'm using a **LoginController**, which redirects **loginfailed** requests to **login.jsp** and is sending an '*error*' attribute with the '*true*' value. The problem is I can't see the message on the *login.jsp* using this expression:

```
${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
```

**Any Idea? Thank You very much!**

Answer (score 0):

On Failure of Authendication, you have asked to redirect to different Page.

```
 response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()
        + "/abc/main/loginfailed");
```

your loginfailed jsp not displayed ? it doesn't has  div like errorblock in login page ? are you seeing different error in loginfailed.jsp ?

EDIT:

Ok I got it . Before `authentication-failure-handler-ref="myAuthErrorHandler"` Spring Handles the failure case and placed message in Session with the key `SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION` . 

After adding the failure handler i.e 
`authentication-failure-handler-ref="myAuthErrorHandler"` 
You have to handle the error. You can set the message in session. or simply call the `super.onAuthenticationFailure` . Your handler is not doing anything !!!

Comment: I already answered you on the update on this post, but I can't figure it out what I'm doing wrong. Maybe the redirect you're telling me? How I should redirect it properly according on what are you telling me on your answer?. Thanks.

Comment: @Ricardo F Updated Answer

Comment: Okay, and how should I rewrite the AuthentificationListener.java to handle this kinds of errors on the failure handler? After fixing this I wanted to use this handler to control login attemps updating the number of attempts. But that's another story. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="color: red">
    Your login attempt was not successful, try again.<br /> Caused :
    ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
</div>
```

use this, remove  form login.jsp

create a properties file name as

- mymessages.properties
- AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=Invalid username or password

and save it and place into your project classpath

and add the the bean in your spring-contex.xml

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>mymessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```